# Apply CSS rules to a nested class inside a div

Tags: html, css

I don’t know exactly how to apply CSS to a nested element. Here is my example code, but I’m looking for a manual that explains all the rules:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="main_text">
    <h2 class="title"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I apply CSS to only the class `title`, nested inside that particular `div`?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You use

```css
#main_text .title {
  /* Properties */
}
```

If you just put a space between the selectors, styles will apply to all children (and children of children) of the first. So in this case, any child element of `#main_text` with the class name `title`. If you use `>` instead of a space, it will only select the direct child of the element, and not children of children, e.g.:

```css
#main_text > .title {
  /* Properties */
}
```

Either will work in this case, but the first is more typically used.

Comment: To learn about these selectors in more details -> 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors  ----> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator#CSS  ----> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator  ----> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 7):

> Use Css Selector for this, or learn more about Css Selector just go here `https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp`

```
#main_text > .title {
  /* Style goes here */
}

#main_text .title {
  /* Style goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to target multiple classes use:

```
#main_text .title, #main_text .title2 {
  /* Properties */
}
```