# Apply style to only nested class of current element

Tags: html, css, class, sass

I am aware in `**CSS**` we can apply a set of styles to nested classes in elements (demonstrated at this page [Apply CSS rules to a nested class inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198327/apply-css-rules-to-a-nested-class-inside-a-div)).

I am now trying to apply a style to a nested class in a div. ***The catch*** here is I am unable to  apply the style to only the nested class of the currently hovered element.

To explain further, here is an HTML snippet:

```
<div class="link-wrap">
     <div class="link"> Github </div>
     <hr class="text-underline">
<div>
    
<div class="link-wrap">
     <div class="link"> Facebook </div>
     <hr class="text-underline">
<div>
```

I would like that if I hover over the Github link, I would alter the style of the `<hr>` for the Github link alone.

Currently, when I do alter the style of the `<hr>`, both of the `<hr>`s have their styles altered at the same time.

I am trying to find a non-JS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this getting close to what you're after?

```css
.link-wrap:hover > .text-underline {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="link-wrap">
  <div class="link"> Github </div>
  <hr class="text-underline">
</div>

<div class="link-wrap">
  <div class="link"> Facebook </div>
  <hr class="text-underline">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.link-wrap:hover > hr {
   your styles
}
```

this will apply `your styles` to any `<hr>` that is the direct descendant of `.link-wrap` that is hovered